# Why are three timelines in Flashpoint?

Tags: dc, adaptation-comparison, the-flash, flashpoint

In *Flashpoint* comic, when Flash enters the Speed Force to stop his younger self from saving his mom, he sees three separate timelines.

These timelines are not shown in the movie.

What are these three timelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_(comics)) for that comic, *(not the film)*, the three timelines are:

- DC (New Earth)
- Vertigo (Earth-13)
- WildStorm (Earth-50)

> Traveling back in time, Barry merges with his earlier self during the attempt to stop Thawne. **While traveling through time, Barry realizes he can see three different timelines — DC (New Earth), Vertigo (Earth-13), and WildStorm (Earth-50).** A mysterious hooded figure (later revealed to be a cursed immortal Pandora) tells him that the world was split into three to weaken them for an impending threat, and must now be reunited to combat it. The DC, Vertigo, and Wildstorm universes are then merged, creating a brand new DC Universe. Barry then wakes up in a similar manner to the beginning of Flashpoint, also retaining all his memories from the alternate timeline. Believing that everything is over, Barry remembers Thomas' letter and gives it to Bruce, who is still the Batman in this timeline. Bruce, deeply touched by his father's sacrifice to ensure his son's life, cries and expresses his gratitude to Barry for informing him of the events that transpired before the timeline was reset.

The citation for that info is listed as:

> Johns, Geoff (w). Flashpoint 5 (August 2011), DC Comics

Comment: So the brand-new DC universe mentioned, is it the current New 52 universe?